# FileSaveDialog with none existing path?

Tags: c#, io, savefiledialog

I got a problem in IO Handling with the SaveFileDialog. As you will see in my following solution I open the Dialog and try to save a file the with the ExportTXT/ExportCSV-methods. The problem now is that typing a Path directly in the Dialog like you would do in the explorer:

> C:\Programs\FolderThatDoesntExist\Errors.txt

I'll always get the Warning: Path not available. Please check it and try again!!!!

And I really don't get it because the:

```
   dlg.CheckPathExists = false;

   property is set to false!

    private void ExportToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
         dlg.FileName = "Errors"; // Default file name
         dlg.DefaultExt = ".csv"; // Default file extension
         dlg.OverwritePrompt = true;
         dlg.CheckPathExists = false;
         dlg.AddExtension = true;
         dlg.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension
         dlg.FileOk += dlg_FileOk;
         // Show save file dialog box
         dlg.ShowDialog();
    }

    void dlg_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
         // Process save file dialog box results
         var extension = Path.GetExtension(((SaveFileDialog)sender).FileName);
         switch (extension.ToLower())
         {
             case ".txt":
                  exportTXT(((SaveFileDialog)sender).FileName);
                  break;
             case ".csv":
                  exportCSV(((SaveFileDialog)sender).FileName);
                  break;
             default:
                  exportTXT(((SaveFileDialog)sender).FileName);
                  break;
          }
    }
```

This method is always called by the Export methods and should ensure the dir will be created.

```
    private void checkDir(string filename)
    {
         string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
         if (!Directory.Exists(path))  // if it doesn't exist, create
         {
             Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Did you make sure the folder/file actually exists?

Comment: As a long time Windows users, it's my understanding that you can't create folders in this manner. At least, I've never done it before. As a long time Windows developer, I wouldn't expect this to work really. Imagine the case where you meant to type in "C:\Programs\FolderThatDoesExist\Errors.txt" instead of "C:\Programs\FolderThatDoesntExist\Errors.txt", now your file is off in some folder that you may never find.

Comment: Ähm yeah I know what you try to explain to me and can you explain this to my customer? I am really not happy with this! But it wasn't my idea and I am not in the position to contradict him.... And please don't tell me I have to code an own FileSaveDialog :D

Comment: You will need to re-align the views of the client. Point out that every other program which they use behaves in the same way. If they won't be brought round ship a program with a file dialog that is simply a form with an edit control into which they can type their file name. When they realise how rubbish this is, ask them to make a choice. You cannot expect to write your own file dialog and make it work well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea that people are usually accustomed to:

1. Have a text box where users can enter a path, by typing it, pasting, or whatever.
2. Have a `Browse` button (or simply `...`) next to it, which opens a `SaveFileDialog` and prompts for a location.
3. When you proceed with the action, you may **warn** your users if the folder doesn't exist and create it, or simply create it automatically. But I would prefer the former approach because it should prevent your app from creating wrong folders in case of typos.

[image]

Alternatively, you can offer a `FolderBrowserDialog` and let your users select a particular folder instead.